# Create an event stream of polymorphic functions - possible? If yes, how?

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

I am currently learning FRP with reactive-banana and wanted to create a stream of random functions. I've come up with this:

```
-- | take number generator, and some pulse event stream, generate random function stream
mkRandom :: (Random a,RandomGen g) => g -> Event t b -> Event t ((a,a) -> a)
mkRandom rng es = (\f -> \r -> fst $ f r) <$> (accumE first $ next <$> es)
  where first = flip randomR rng
        next _ prev range = randomR range g
          where (a,g) = prev range
```

It seems to work, I can use it like this:

```
randFuncs = mkRandom rnd (pulse 1000 time)
some = ($ (0,10::Int)) <$> randFuncs
```

But, of course, when I try to share that stream to generate numbers of a different type:

```
some2 = ($ (0,10::Double)) <$> randFuncs
```

The type checker complains, which I understand. Then I tried to generalize the function to the following:

```
mkRandom :: (RandomGen g) => g -> Event t b -> Event t (forall a. Random a => (a,a) -> a)
```

Then GHC complained about illegal polymorphic signature and whether I'd like to enable ImpredicativeTypes. I did it and for quite a while tried to annotate everything to make it work, but GHC always complained that it could not match the types.

My question is - is it possible to do what I want? Do I really need ImpredicativeTypes for that or am I just doing it wrong?

I thought RankNTypes should be enough for it, but I have no experience with such extensions yet.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

For the record, now my solution based on the helpful response is:

```
newtype RandomSource = Rand { getRand :: forall a. (Random a) => (a,a) -> [a] }

-- | take number generator and some pulse event stream, generate randomness stream
mkRandom :: RandomGen g => g -> Event t a -> Behavior t RandomSource
mkRandom rng es = fst <$> (accumB (next id (id,rng)) $ next <$> es)
  where next _ (_,rng) = (Rand $ flip randomRs g1, g2)
          where (g1,g2) = split rng

-- | take a rand. source, a range and a pulse, return stream of infinite lists of random numbers
randStream :: Random a => Behavior t RandomSource -> (a,a) -> Event t b -> Event t [a]
randStream funcs range pulse = ($ range) . getRand <$> funcs <@ pulse
```

Comment: I've been told reactive-banana 1.0 (current `master`) will simplify the types in non-trivial and substantial ways, such as not requiring `RankNTypes` (in some scenarios?), so you might give it a try.

Comment: @ErikAllik The API changes for reactive-banana 1.0 mainly concern the type parameter `t`. The question at hand is unrelated to this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ImpredicativeTypes` is an incredibly brittle extension that is not really supported or maintained and so keeps breaking further in new GHC versions.

A much better working option is to use `RankNTypes` together with a `newtype` wrapper:

```
newtype PolyRandFun = PR { getPR :: forall a. Random a => (a,a) -> a) }
```

This requires you to explicitly wrap and unwrap the newtype constructor, but otherwise works fine for passing around polymorphic functions like this.

Unfortunately I foresee another problem in this case. Different `Random a` instances use their random generator a *different* amount, and in the case of e.g. `Integer` the amount of primitive random numbers generated to build the `Integer` result will even depend on the size of the range. So you cannot get the next `g` without knowing the type and range used when actually calling your functions.

Fortunately there's a function in the `System.Random` API that can get around this: `split` gives you a new random generator that can be passed into subcalculations when you really need to generate several random values entirely independently.

Comment: Alas, I can confirm that `ImpredicativeTypes` is very brittle – but can you say _why_ it's so little-maintained? I feel it should be a rather natural extension to `RankN`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout [Explanation by Simon PJ](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2014-February/024684.html)

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I personally cannot, but my impression is that it's a "deep" problem. GHC's type checker is apparently fundamentally incapable of doing it right, and no one knows how to write a type checker that does it right, offers all the other pretty things, and gives vaguely human-readable error messages.

Comment: Thanks! The necessary unwrapping is a bit unsatisfactory, but it works!